# "No las hemos de olvidar" on the obelisk

Tags: gramática

I read that on the obelisk of Buenos Aires is displayed "No las hemos de olvidar." I assume that it means "We haven't forgotten them (the Malvinas)." But shouldn't that be "No las hemos *olvidado*" by the rules of the present perfect tense? Or is 'conjugated haber' + 'de' + 'infinitive' an alternate rule? Thank you.

Comment: It means: We must not forget it. [the Malvinas War]

Comment: I attended a British school in Rosario Argentina in the 1950s.  Needless to say,  their teachings about the Falkland islands were, ahem, interesting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Haber de" + infinitive is a rather formal verb phrase used in very restricted cases to indicate future obligation. See acceptation (2) [here](https://dle.rae.es/haber).

"No las hemos de olvidar" means: We shall not forget them.

Actually, this sentence appears in Malvinas hymn:

> ### MARCHA DE LAS MALVINAS
>
> Tras su manto de neblinas, 
> **no las hemos de olvidar**.
>
> "¡Las Malvinas, Argentinas!", 
> clama el viento y ruge el mar.
>
> Ni de aquellos horizontes 
> nuestra enseña han de arrancar, 
> pues su blanco está en los montes 
> y en su azul se tiñe el mar.
>
> ¡Por ausente, por vencido 
> bajo extraño pabellón, 
> ningún suelo más querido; 
> de la patria en la extensión!
>
> ¿Quién nos habla aquí de olvido, 
> de renuncia, de perdón? ... 
> ¡Ningún suelo más querido, 
> de la patria en la extensión.
>
> ¡Rompa el manto de neblinas, 
> como un sol, nuestro ideal: 
> "Las Malvinas, Argentinas 
> en dominio ya inmortal"!
>
> Y ante el sol de nuestro emblema, 
> pura, nítida y triunfal, 
> brille ¡oh Patria!, en tu diadema 
> la perdida perla austral.
>
> Coro 
> ¡Para honor de nuestro emblema 
> para orgullo nacional, 
> brille ¡oh Patria!, en tu diadema 
> la pérdida perla austral.

([Source](https://www.argentina.gob.ar/sites/default/files/marcha-malvinas.pdf))

Comment: We **must not** forget them. Not will not. :)

Comment: I agree that mainly in BrE "shall" is the future auxiliary for the first person. However, "shall" can indicate obligation with all persons: "We shall not forget them" = "They shall not be forgotten".

Comment: In AmE also. But if you use shall, it can be understood as a promise. An obligation is better with must and to translate the idiom.

Answer (score 1):

**"No las hemos de olvidar"**

---

Información General

"*No las hemos de olvidar", es parte de una canción Argentina, ¿Qué es la Marcha de Malvinas?, que se hizo conocida durante el conflicto bélico de 1982. Sin embargo, su origen se remonta al 9 de julio de 1939, donde durante la presidencia de Roberto M. Ortizse creó la “Junta de Recuperación de las Malvinas*”.

*"El objetivo de esta junta era contribuir a la difusión y conocimiento del tema entre la población. Por ello una de las actividades principales fue la de organizar un concurso poético-musical.
Así es como el 3 de enero de 1941 se dio a conocer la composición ganadora en un acto público con ubicación en el Salón Augusteo de Buenos Aires.
La Marcha de las Malvinas fue compuesta por José Tieri y Carlos Obligado".*

*"José Tieri, quien proporciono la musica en 1940, demuestra en su contenido el sentido de pertenencia de ese territorio ocupado por otra nación y el deseo profundo de recuperarlo, sentimiento que sentían todos los argentinos ayer, hoy y siempre"*.

Tras su manto de neblinas,

**no las hemos de olvidar**.

"¡Las Malvinas, Argentinas!",

clama el viento y ruge el mar.

*"Este párrafo inicial hace referencia a las características climáticas de las islas, en donde predomina la neblina, al mismo tiempo que los fenómenos naturales proclaman la soberanía argentina sobre ese territorio".*

---

*Texto anteriores de Leonardo González*

---

**No las hemos de olvidar.**

Explicación

Las islas Malvinas están situadas en el Mar Argentino a unos 600 km, aproximadamente, de la costa patagónica, poseen una superficie de 11.718 km2 y se compone de dos islas principales, Soledad y Gran Malvina, y aproximadamente 200 islotes más pequeños.

La frase que tratamos es un "exhorto", un "llamamiento" realizado a la nación donde hay una apelación ó incitación con palabras dirigidas a alguien, en este caso a la Nación Argentina, para que realicen una determinada conducta, en esta ocasión que nunca dejen de olvidarse. Este tipo de frases suelen ser consideradas como *un mandato u ordenes* sin llegar a utilizar la imposición de un imperativo, y por tanto se expresan con infinitivo.

No las hemos de olvidar, las vamos a recordar, las tenemos que conmemorar, las vamos a llevar en nuestro corazón. Otros, "Al campo tenemos que llevarlas", "Al cine hemos de entrar", "No les tenemos que abrir... **Se trata de exhortos que dan fuerza, estimulan ó impelen nuestra conducta para llevar a cabo una acción.** No se trata en este caso del Pretérito Perfecto del verbo olvidar, "Nosotros las hemos olvidado", "Nosotros no las hemos olvidado".

"No hemos de olvidar a las Islas Malvinas", "Nosotros no hemos" de olvidar, se utiliza la primera persona del plural "Nosotros" del verbo "haber", en este caso con una partícula negativa. Nosotros no las hemos de olvidar ó Nosotros no hemos de olvidarlas.

El componente "las", "No las hemos de olvidar", en este caso es el pronombre, es decir, sustituye al nombre, (Islas Malvinas) y desempeña la función de complemento directo.

En estos casos, cuando el pronombre desempeña la función de complemento directo, deben usarse las formas lo, los para el masculino (singular y plural, respectivamente) y la, las para el femenino (singular y plural, respectivamente): ¿Has visto a Juan? Sí, lo vi ayer.

Comment: Cuando se cita literalmente el texto de otro autor, se entrecomilla, haciendo referencia a quien lo escribe, ya que es quien lo ha escrito. Son normas básicas de actuación y conducta.

Si lo que se hace es fusilar un texto, sin poner comillas, y sin citar a su autor, estamos diciendo que nosotros lo hemos escrito. Cuando esto sucede, estamos ante una flagrante y grave violación de la autoría de un texto. En otras palabras: un PLAGIO.

Texto de Leonardo González:
https://viapais.com.ar/documentos-malvinas/1271334-marcha-de-malvinas-la-historia-desconocida-detras-de-la-emocionante-cancion/

Comment: Si no lo corriges, lo elevaré a StackExchange.
¿Y todo, para conseguir más puntos, y más visibilidad?

Comment: Gracias por indicármelo, ese texto lo encontré en otro lugar al señalado con la misma redacción por lo visto y sin ninguna referencia a nombrealguno. https://www.a24.com/actualidad/marcha-de-las-malvinas-09092019_r1mHEg48B